# Noise due to Fluorescent light in a signal from a LED

Tags: noise

I measured a signal coming from a LED using a sensor. The signal is Amplitude Modulated, so I expect its spectrum to be moved by the carrier frequency.

I am trying to explain the symmetric harmonics that appear in both sides of the peaks. I believe they might originate from the Fluorescent lights of the lab. I made a model where I added a square wave to the envelope and that seems to reproduce the effect in Matlab, but I am having a hard time finding the frequency of the noise.

Could people let me know if I am on the right track? If so, how can I go about finding the frequency of the interference?

I real online that Fluorescent lights produce electromagnetic radiation that can interfere with measurements. Could that, rather than the actually light be the culprit?

The signal is given by:

> S(t)=cos(f*2*pi*t)*cos(fc*2*pi*t)

When fc = 1000Hz and f=30Hz.
Here is the signal's spectrum. Note the added Harmonics:
[image]
Bigger picture:
[image]

**EDIT** I came back and measured again after covering the system to hide it from the light. The noise is still there, so it is probably not due Flurescent. My latest theory is that the noise is due to AC currents inside the system, maybe due to over sampling. I will open a new question for descussing this as it is not related to this question.

Comment: What if you turn off the lights

Comment: Well, I tried it, and it seems the noise is still there. My new theory is that I may have oversampled and this caused some kind of AC noise inside the device.